# XmlNode.OwnerDocument.ChildNodes is empty

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I get a XmlElement from a web service. I get something unexpected because `xmlElement.OwnerDocument.ChildNodes` is empty. How is that possible?

This is the xml:

```
<tns1:VideoSource xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics">
   <MotionAlarm wstop:topic="true" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl">
   </MotionAlarm>
</tns1:VideoSource>
```

Comment: If the element returned is only a discrete copy of an original, it might not have an owner.

Comment: Give us your data...

Answer (score 0):

I tested you xml with the code below and there are children like you said.  I suspect there may be some white characters that is creating an error.  If you got data from a website (probably a stream) there may be some null characters at the end of the stream that is invisible.  Make sure your stream class is using UTF8 encoding.  The default encoding in some streams is Ascii which can change characters and add padding character which may create issues.

```
           string input =
                "<tns1:VideoSource xmlns:tns1=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics\">" +
                  "<MotionAlarm wstop:topic=\"true\" xmlns:wstop=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1\" xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl\">" +
                  "</MotionAlarm>" +
                "</tns1:VideoSource>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(input);
            XmlNodeList videoSource = doc.ChildNodes;
            XmlNodeList motionAlarm = videoSource[0].ChildNodes;​
```